# Accessing an Ubuntu share from Mac OS X (Snow Leopard)

Tags: 11.04, mac, share

I have an external hard drive hooked up to my desktop running Ubuntu.  I've shared the folder by simply right-clicking, going to Sharing Options, and clicking on 'Share this folder'.

How can I access this share from my mac laptop?  It doesn't show up in the Network folder, and I tried smb://ip_address/ with no success.

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind-- restart did the trick.  Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Which computer did you restart?

Comment: I restarted Ubuntu with my external plugged in, and then it showed up on my Mac.